# Write LoadRunner scripts

Tags: testing, loadrunner

I have read the Load runner basics and understood an overview of the components of Load Runner and general workflow.

As its Load Testing of a website, I need to plan  real time scenarios  of the functionality of the website with example 100 users who log-in simultaneously.

In Load runner,I need to create all these users that  emulate steps of real users using the application These which would be virtual users…Vuser.

Could you all please help me writing  this script? please help me by giving a script to create a vuser and description of the script.

The component  is VuGen (Virtual User Generator) of Load runner. VuGen then  also runs them. How to execute it?

Comment: This question is probably more suitable for [sqa.se].

Answer (score 0):

Rohit,

There is no substitute for training in the tool.   The path of self education in this space is one which has been trod by many and the results are almost universally poor for the traveler.    Affirm your core skills related to development, test, project management, systems analysis, monitoring and diagnostic actions, Attend training, work with a mentor.  That is the path to success.

James Pulley
Moderator (LoadRunner Yahoo Groups, Advanced LoadRunner Yahoo Group, lr-LoadRunner Google Group, SQA Forums LoadRunner, SQAForums WinRunner, Linkedin LoadRunner, Linkedin LoadRunnerbythehour, The Pithy Performance list)

Comment: I also agree that the best way to go is using a Mentor/Teacher in this case

Comment: As a follow on to my comment yesterday, your use of the term "simultaneously" could have some serious consequences in the generation of errors.   In general, unless the sessions in question are controlled by a clock tick, users arrive and depart in a chaotic fashion.   You may have tight clustering, such as around a specific time where all users needs to sign into a customer service solution to accept phone calls, but true simultaneity to the level you describe does not occur with organic computing units.

Answer (score 0):

You can find useful articles on Performance Testing principals and also tips & tricks for performance testing tools (including HP Loadrunner) on this site: 
http://www.perftesting.co.uk/

Answer (score 0):

the best way of studying and understanding loadrunner is the buit in tutorial. 
after installation you can get a pre-installed 10-day evaluation license, under which you can use the extensive tutorial of writing and creating the script.
good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Start with this,
 https://automation-performance.blogs...e-testing.html

Then (in sequence)
 https://automation-performance.blogs...oadrunner.html

https://automation-performance.blogs...scripting.html

https://automation-performance.blogs...nner-tool.html

Thereafter few other topics,

https://automation-performance.blogs...oadrunner.html

https://automation-performance.blogs...ttp-codes.html

https://automation-performance.blogs...ation-and.html

Once you are done with these, you will start getting some hang of what you are into.....you can take it forward from there

And for advance learning of Performance Engineering you can go to following link,

https://automation-performance.blogs...gineering.html